# Exception handling in Event-Driven Async WCF service call

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception, windows-phone-8.1

Question concerns the Windows Phone 8.1 SL application that uses a WCF service to connect to and retrieve information from the database. How do we handle the communication error exception to the database? Suppose that the service is turned on, and we have access to it, but the service does not have access to the database for some reason. Whether such error handling should be on the side of the WCF? If yes then how should it be written to friendly display information for user, like messagebox?

The second thing: I decided myself to simulate the lack of access to the WCF service. To achieve this I've just changed the IP address to the service. I want to handle this exception from the application side but I always get error exception in Visual Studio. Any advise what the error class is responsible for handling the communication error with the service?

I'm trying something like this:

```
public partial class Kurs : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    CenyMiejscaService.CenyMiejscaServiceClient cenyMiejscaUsluga;
    Dictionary<DateTime, double> kurs;


    public Kurs()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        kurs = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();

        try
        {
            cenyMiejscaUsluga = new CenyMiejscaService.CenyMiejscaServiceClient();
            cenyMiejscaUsluga.PobierzKursRublaCompleted += cenyMiejscaUsluga_PobierzKursRublaCompleted;

            cenyMiejscaUsluga.PobierzKursRublaAsync();
        }
        catch(CommunicationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

But I receive only exception which Visual Studio throws:
[image]

Comment: Visual Studio is not throwing the exception. .NET is throwing the exception, and you're not catching it.

Comment: I tried but this is Async method. So I have to catch that exception somewhere else, I've read a lot of articles but can't find a solution.

Comment: I think you need two question posts here, not a single post containing two questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the error handling is in the WCF service. What can you do about the error? Pretty much nothing because the database is down and you can't correct that. All that the WCF service should do is relay the error to the client. The client can then interpret the error and show a message.

Handle errors where you can actually do something about them.

I'm unclear on the second question. It seems you just need to catch the resulting `CommunicationException`. Maybe the `InnerException` contains something useful. If not there's not much you can do. The exception hierarchy in .NET is deeply flawed because it often does not allow you to differentiate between different errors.

Comment: InnerException also can't be catched, and Visual Studio throws exception. I just want to prevent from crashing application when for some reason there isn't available access to the WCF service.

Comment: You can catch any exception, analyze the inner exception and `throw;` if you don't want to handle it. Is your question answered?

Comment: But I want to handle it. I want to show `MessageBox` when for some reason the application doesn't have access to the service. I assume that catch block is never used because `PobierzKursRublaAsync` method is asynchronous?

Comment: You probably have to handle the error in cenyMiejscaUsluga_PobierzKursRublaCompleted. Search for "WCF async error handling".

Comment: I don't use the event-driven async pattern that you're using, but @usr is correct - the exception should be in the EventArgs which are passed to `cenyMiejscaUsluga_PobierzKursRublaCompleted`. Have you set a breakpoint in that method? You'll have to F5/"Continue" past this debugger stop in order to get there.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, oh it works I can handle the exception in that method! But why .net throws that exception first? If I will have to test my application because of lack of access to the service it will be very annoying because of this exception throws by .net. Can I do anything with this?

Comment: Sorry, do what with what? You're not being very clear.

Comment: Sorry. Even if I handle exception in `cenyMiejscaUsluga_PobierzKursRublaCompleted` method by using `e.Error` - .NET still throws Communication Exception first as I've shown in a screen on my question post. How can I prevent throwing exception by .NET in `EndPobierzKursRubla`?